# Prove $0\le a_n \le a_{n+1} \le 1\ $ for all $n$, if $ a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_n}{2}}$ and $0\le a_1\le 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I know that $0\le a_1\le 1$ and $ a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_n}{2}}$ for all $ n\ge 1$

Prove that $0\le a_n\le 1\ $ for all $n$, and $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$ for all $n$.

I think I shall assume the opposite and show that this leads to a false conclusion.

I don't know where to start and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Are you sure you copied this right ? $a_{n+1}$ does not depend on $a_n$ ...

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the comments. I will now try them, I'll be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence is $$a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+a_n}{2}}$$
Let's go step by step. First, we'll prove that $$0\leq a_n\leq 1$$ for all $n$. 
We are given that $0\leq a_1\leq 1$. Now suppose $0\leq a_k\leq 1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This gives $$ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq a_{k+1} = \left( \frac{a_{k} + 1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \leq 1$$ which means $0\leq a_{k+1} \leq 1$. By the principle of weak induction, we have $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ for all $n$.

To show $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we outline a proof by contradiction. Suppose $a_{n+1} < a_n$ *for some* $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using the recurrence in the problem, this would mean $$2a_n^3 - a_n - 1 > 0 \implies (a_n - 1)\left(2\left(a_n + \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \right) > 0 \implies a_n > 1$$ which is a contradiction, since we have already shown that $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
So we have $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as desired.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. Where did $2a_{n}^{3}-a_n-1>0$ came from? EDIT: Nevermind. Understood it now.

Comment: Yeah, just used the recurrence!

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

- I'd strongly suggest you try mathematical induction.
- You'll probably find the following facts useful:

  i. If $\ 0\le x\le1\ $ then $\ 0\le\frac{1+x}{2}\le1 $.

  ii. If $\ 0\le y\le 1\ $ then $\ 0\le\sqrt[3]{y}\le1\ $.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{2}}$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to prove it by induction ! You have $0\le a_1\le1$ and you can prove that $a_1\le a_2$. Now that you have the base case, you can assume $0\le a_n\le1$ and $a_{n-1}\le a_{n}$ and prove that $0\le a_{n+1}\le1$ and $a_n\le a_{n+1}$. (Use the hint given by one of the answers above)

Answer (score 1):

$a_n \ge 0$ is trivial.

$2a_{n+1}^3-2=a_n-1 \implies 2(1-a_{n+1})(a_{n+1}^2+a_{n+1}+1)=1-a_n$

Therefore $a_n \le 1 \implies a_{n+1}\le 1$

Finally $1-a_n \ge 2(1-a_{n+1})\cdot 1 \ge 1-a_{n+1} \implies a_{n+1} \ge a_n$.